# music player in iphone simulator 4.2

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator, mpmusicplayercontroller, audio-player

I am trying to add music player to my iphone app using the MediaPlayer framework. I dont have a real device with me and want to test it on simulator. But, the simulator doesnt support MPMusicPlayer and crashes when i run the [add media app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html). 
Is there a way I could test MPMusicPlayer on simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add music to the simulator so MPMusicPlayer will fail. It will have to be tested on a device.